# Powershell上でmosquitto_pubを " 使ったpublishメッセージに”文字を送りたい。

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Powershell上で以下を実行した際に、`{"test":10}` という文字列をメッセージとして送りたかったので、

```
ps> .\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{\"test\":10}"
```

を実行しようとしてもエスケープ文字が解釈できずエラーになってしまいます。

```
ps> .\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{`"test`":10}"
```

は、送信できますが、subscriberは、`{test:10}` と解釈します。

```
ps> .\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{""test"":10}"**
```

も送信できますが、 `{test:10}` と解釈します。実際には、どのように送ればよいのでしょうか？

コマンドプロンプトでは、

```
> .\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{\"test\":10}"
```

で送ることができ、subscriberは、 `{"test":10}` と解釈できています。

Comment: Markdownの都合上、 `**` での強調表示では ` \ ` が消えていました。実際に入力したコマンドライン文字列を再確認していただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX系OSはshellがコマンドライン引数を解釈し、グロブ展開（`*.txt`などを実ファイル名に展開）してからプロセスが起動されます。
しかし、Windowsではshellにそのような機能がないため、各プロセスのスタートアップルーチンがコマンドライン引数を解釈し、グロブ展開を行います。その上で、shell（`cmd.exe`;コマンドプロンプトやPowerShell）は各プロセスのスタートアップルーチンを邪魔しないようにコマンドライン引数を解釈しています。
要するに、**コマンドライン引数は２段階で解釈されるため、それを見越してコマンドライン入力する必要があります**。

---

> コマンドプロンプトでは、
>
> ```
> .\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{\"test\":10}"
> ```
>
> で送ることができ、subscriberは、 `{"test":10}` と解釈できています。

`cmd.exe`のエスケープ文字は`^`です。`^`が含まれていない以上、`cmd.exe`に渡した引数はそのままプロセスに渡されます。つまり`.\mosquitto_pub`が受け取るコマンドライン引数は

```
-h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{\"test\":10}"
```

です。PowerShellでこのコマンドライン引数を再現するためには

```
.\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "{\`"test\`":10}"
```

辺りでどうでしょうか？ （[PowerShellのエスケープ文字は ` です](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3)）

これでダメな場合、外側の`"`も保持するように

```
.\mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t spresense/mqtt -m "`"{\`"test\`":10}`""
```

とする必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど。そうなのですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。